# how can I read data from database using button next and prev

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Module Module1
    Public con As New odbcConnection
    Public cmd As New OdbcCommand
    Public dr As OdbcDataReader

    Function connect()
        con.ConnectionString = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};database=sample;option=0;port=3306;server=localhost;uid=root;pwd=root" local connection
        con.Open()
    End Function

    Function Disconnect()
        con.Close()
    End Function
End Module
```

Im using this code to retrieve data from my database

```
Private Sub search_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsearch.Click
    Disconnect()
    connect()
    Using da As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("Select  model, controlNo, revLvl, dataAq, maker, makerControlNo, revItem, reasonRev, remarks, endorseDate, a, b, c, d, e, frameSize, framProf, fedMark, imgOr, imgPos, txtMark, actual, required from dbstencil.tbldata where controlNo = '" & search.Text & "'and model = '" & searchmodel.Text & "'", con)
        MyDataTable.Clear()
        da.Fill(MyDataTable)
    End Using
    Disconnect()
    CurrentRowNumber = 0
    DisplayRecord()
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    #Do Code here
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrev_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrev.Click
    #Do Code here
End Sub
```

Comment: please try looking at limit clause of mysql

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about that.

Comment: Also a FROM clause, but especially don't use string concatenation to include user data in an sql query. It's crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Dataset` or `DataTable` instead of `DataReader`. You don't need to keep the connection open all the time.

Here is some sample untested code for you.

```
'' declare these variables at form level
Private MyDataTable As New DataTable
Private CurrentRowNumber As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsearch.Click
    Connect()
    Using da As New Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("Select columnA, columnB, columnC, columnD FROM TableName where columnA= '" & search.Text & "'and columnB= '" & searchmodel.Text & "'", con)
        MyDataTable.Clear()
        da.Fill(MyDataTable)
    End Using
    Disconnect()
    CurrentRowNumber = 0
    DisplayRecord()
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    CurrentRowNumber += 1
    DisplayRecord()
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrev_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPrev.Click
    CurrentRowNumber -= 1
    DisplayRecord()
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayRecord()
    With MyDataTable.Rows(CurrentRowNumber)
        columnA.Text = .Item("columnA").ToString
        columnB.Text = .Item("columnB").ToString
        columnC.Text = .Item("columnC").ToString
        columnD.Text = .Item("columnD").ToString
    End With
    btnPrev.Enabled = True
    btnNext.Enabled = True
    If CurrentRowNumber = 0 Then btnPrev.Enabled = False
    If CurrentRowNumber = MyDataTable.Rows.Count - 1 Then btnNext.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This is better loading is good but in my next and prev not working, whats the problem here?

Comment: @user3795723, You are missing the table name (FROM clause) in your SQL statement. I just copied your query as it is in the sample code I gave.

Comment: Yea I forgot about that, Thanks again.

Comment: last question sir. I want to disable my next button or prev button when they search the last data, for example in next button, it reach the end data, the next button will be enabled = false or so that the user will have no choice to click the previous button.

Comment: If `CurrentRowNumber` is 0 then you are at first record. If it is equal to `MyDataTable.Rows.Count - 1` then you are at last record. You can easily use this information to enable/disable the buttons. I updated the code above to show you how.